# What are fine-grained and coarse-grained timeout

Tags: tcp, ip

What are the definitions of fine-grained and coarse-grained timeout?

I googled them, but only get their properties from lectures and academic papers. But I still don't know what they really mean.

Answer (score 4):

TCP uses an estimate of the Round Trip Time (RTT) to guess when a packet has to be received by the other end. If that timer exceeds, the packet is assumed lost and retransmitted.

In TCP Reno the RTT is computed using a **coarse-grained** timer. This means that, say, every 500ms it is checked whether some sent packet is received or not. If it is, the RTT is the time of the timer, if not the timer checks again in 500ms. Of ourse, 500ms is an arbitrary value but this is essentially how it works.

TCP Vegas, for example, uses a **fine-grained** timer, using the system's time at the point of sending and point of receiving a segment to compute the RTT.

See [RFC 2988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2988) for details.